# How to use purrr to obtain intermediate results as well as final results in R

Tags: r, purrr

When using purrr (map() for example), I'm interested in retaining the intermediate results as well as the final result of the purrr function.  Consider the following map function:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

list <- c(4, 8, 12, 16)

test <- map(list, function(x){
  if (x > 14) {
    min <-  0.005
  } else if (x > 10) {
    min <-  0.025
  } else if (x >= 5) {
    min <-  0.05 
  } else {
    min <-  0.1
  }
  
  avg <- 1/x
  max <- avg + (avg - min) 
  
  DF <- (seq(max, min, length.out = x))
  })
```

This map function works properly and creates a list of 4 (titled as "test"), each consisting of a list that represent a series of decimals that add to 1.0.  In addition to this list of final results I'd also like to extract the intermediate results.  For example in the case of x = 4, I'd like the resultant list titled, "test" to also keep track of the intermediate results.

For x = 4:

```
min = 0.1
avg = 0.25
max = 0.4
```

I would like to know how to include these values of min, avg, and max in the "test" list well as the overall result.  In my research I thought that walk() may provide what I'm needed, but it isn't what I'm looking for after all.  Is there any purrr function that is similar to map, or safely, where I can specify a list of intermediate results to include in the results?  Maybe it is some combination of mutate and map?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Modify your function to return a list with all of the values you care about

Comment: So, I would just add an extra line of code at the end to combine it all?  Like: DFtest <- c(DF, min, max)?  Although I tried this and it just adds the the variables to the list of doubles that I created in the DF code.

Comment: Last line of the function would be something like `list(min,max,avg,DF)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand a bit on the comments, if you want multiple results from a single function you can return a list of results. In your case, this would mean modifying the function to `return` a list containing the values of interest.

Because you are using `map` to apply this function over a vector of inputs, the result will be a list of lists. Four lists (one for each values in `lst`) which are each made up of a list of values (here I am returning `x`,`min`, `max`, `avg` and `DF`).

You can also name your lists so it is easier to keep track. Here I use `setNames` to name the elements of the list before the `return` call.

```
library(purrr)

lst <- c(4, 8, 12, 16)

map(lst, function(x){

  if (x > 14) {
    min <-  0.005
  } else if (x > 10) {
    min <-  0.025
  } else if (x >= 5) {
    min <-  0.05 
  } else {
    min <-  0.1
  }
  
  avg <- 1/x
  max <- avg + (avg - min) 
  
  DF <- (seq(max, min, length.out = x))

  results <- setNames(list(x, min,max,avg,DF), c('x','min', 'max', 'avg', 'DF'))
  return(results)
})


#-----
[[1]]
[[1]]$x
[1] 4

[[1]]$min
[1] 0.1

[[1]]$max
[1] 0.4

[[1]]$avg
[1] 0.25

[[1]]$DF
[1] 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1

[[2]]
[[2]]$x
[1] 8
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing lists and vectors in R. This makes me suspect you may have a Python background. `c(4, 8, 12, 16)` is a vector in R and only contains a 1 dimensional array of data. `list(4,6,12,16)` is a list and can contain multiple dimensions (in this case it has just one).

For your question we can return a list by defining `list(min = min, avg = avg, ...)` and then return that list.

However, there is also a way to do this without a map statement at all in dplyr using a dataframe with a nested list for DF. A dataframe is just a special type of list structured into columns.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

vec <- c(4, 8, 12, 16)

test <- map(vec, function(x){
  if (x > 14) {
    min <-  0.005
  } else if (x > 10) {
    min <-  0.025
  } else if (x >= 5) {
    min <-  0.05 
  } else {
    min <-  0.1
  }
  
  avg <- 1/x
  max <- avg + (avg - min) 
  
  DF <- (seq(max, min, length.out = x))
  return(list(min = min, avg = avg, max = max, DF = DF))
})
# To see the result for the first value in the list aka 4
test[[1]]
# $`min`
# [1] 0.1
# 
# $avg
# [1] 0.25
# 
# $max
# [1] 0.4
# 
# $DF
# [1] 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1

# Prefered alternative:
#dplyr no map needed
df <- tibble(x = vec) %>%
  mutate(
    min = case_when(
        x > 14 ~ .005,
        x > 10 ~ .025,
        x >= 5 ~ 0.05,
        TRUE ~ 0.1
      ),
    avg = 1/x,
    max = avg + (avg - min)
  ) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(DF = list(seq(max, min, length.out = x))) %>%
  ungroup()
df
# A tibble: 4 x 5
#         x   min    avg   max DF        
#     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <list>    
#   1     4 0.1   0.25   0.4   <dbl [4]> 
#   2     8 0.05  0.125  0.2   <dbl [8]> 
#   3    12 0.025 0.0833 0.142 <dbl [12]>
#   4    16 0.005 0.0625 0.12  <dbl [16]>
# To view DF for 4 you can do
df[[1,5]][[1]]
# or 
df$DF[[1]]
# 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1
```